# Rendering previous state instead of current value selected in dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wrote the dropdown component that passes a selected value back to parent via callback function. From there I would like to simply render the selected value below the dropdown. Instead I have rendered previous state. I have no idea why that works like that, could someone explain me my app's behaviour and maybe give a hint how to fix it? I don't even know where to look for the answers.

index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

import { Dropdown } from './components/dropdown'

class App extends Component {

  state = {
      response: "",
      currA: ""
    };

    componentDidMount() {
      this.callApi()
        .then(res => this.setState({ response: res.express }))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }

    callApi = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('/main');
      const body = await response.json();

      if (response.status !== 200) throw Error(body.message);

      return body;
    };

    calculateRate = (currA) => {
      this.setState({currA: currA});
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div>
          <Dropdown callbackFromParent={this.calculateRate}/>
        </div>
        <p>
          {this.state.currA}
        </p>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

dropdown.js

```
import React from 'react';

export class Dropdown extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      list: [],
      selected: ""
    };
  }

componentDidMount(){
  fetch('https://api.fixer.io/latest')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(myJson => {
      this.setState({ list: Object.keys(myJson.rates) });
    });
}

change(event) {
  this.setState({ selected: event.target.value });
  this.props.callbackFromParent(this.state.selected);
}

  render(){
    var selectCurr = (curr) =>
     <select
      onChange={this.change.bind(this)}
      value={this.state.currA}
     >
     {(this.state.list).map(x => <option>{x}</option>)}
     </select>;

    return (
      <div>
        {selectCurr()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your setState() is not a synchronous call, it might be that your callback is firing before the state of your dropdown is actually modified.  You could try using the callback on setState...

```
change(event) {
  this.setState({ 
    selected: event.target.value 
  }, () => {this.props.callbackFromParent(event.target.value)});
  ;
}
```

...Or if your parent component is the only thing that cares about the selected value (my guess from your snip), you don't need to update the dropdown state at all.

```
change(event) {
    this.props.callbackFromParent(event.target.value;)
}
```

Good luck!

[Documentation:](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater, callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update has been applied. If you need to set the state based on the previous state, read about the updater argument below.